# $argv not defined when executing PHP CLI script from Windows 10 XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to execute a PHP script from the command line in Windows 10 while using XAMPP for localhost.

From the Git terminal application on Windows 10, I'm running the following command:

```
/c/xampp/php/php.exe /path/to/script/script.php arg1=val1
```

The script executes correctly, but when I try to do the following:

```
print_r($argv);
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: argv in /path/to/script/script.php on line line-#.
```

Also, `php_sapi_name()` returns `cli`, so I should be good, but both `$argv` and `$argc` return as undefined.

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [PHP docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), `$argv` and `$argc` variable are not defined unless such feature is explicitly enabled via `php.ini`'s [register_argc_argv](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv), so check your config file first.

But instead of depending on runtime environment configurable I'd rather recommend keeping `register_argc_argv` option off and recommend your code to use `$_SERVER['argv']` / `$_SERVER['argc']` instead. This will work because the `$_SERVER` superglobal is populated in CLI mode too, and these keys are always present, regardless of state of `register_argc_argv` config.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.